# Find minimum number of groups such that no enemies in same group

Tags: math, combinatorics

Suppose each student has x enemies. We need to form groups in a class of 100 students such that no enemies are in the same group. Find the minimum number of groups needed in the worst case for x=1,2,3. How to proceed with this question ?

Comment: What have you done so far? By the way, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871578/show-that-in-a-group-of-10-people-where-any-2-are-either-friends-or-enemies-t) might help

Comment: I don't know how i can approach it without brute approach of thinking. How can i approach the problem logically ?

Comment: The question isn't clear.   Should you be grouping them such that no student in the group has more than one enemy to worry about?  Sounds like a classification with constraints to me.

Comment: Hint: first try to solve the simplest case, x=1. If enemies are represented as a graph, what kind of graph is with x=1? And what kind of graph is with x=2?

Comment: @Ante I thought I saw where you were going with this but, for x=2, can't you have "triangles" A, B, C, where each is an enemy of the other two? Or is that what you're saying? I thought you were implying the graph would be a tree.

Comment: @barrycarter It is not a tree, because leaves have only one enemy. For x=2 it is one or more circles.

Comment: @duffymo the question is how many minimum groups are needed in the worst case such that no enemies are in the same group. given each student has fixed number of enemies say x. Now i have to find answer for x=1,2,3.

Comment: Does "A is an enemy of B" imply "B is an enemy of A"?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a graph with vertices representing students and edges representing whether the two students are enemies.

A graph where each vertex has *k* adjacent vertices is called a [*k*-regular graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph).

> The necessary and sufficient conditions for a *k*-regular graph of order n to exist are that *k < n* and that *n*k* is even.

Dividing the vertices of a graph into groups such that no two vertices in a group are adjacent is called [vertex coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring), and the smallest number of such groups is called the [chromatic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticNumber.html) of the graph.

So, your problem can be stated as follows: Given two integers *n* and *k < n*, find the maximum chromatic number of a *k*-regular graph with *n* vertices.

To solve this, the [Brooks' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem) can be used:

> In a connected graph in which every vertex has at most Δ neighbors,
>   the vertices can be colored with only Δ colors, except for two cases,
>   complete graphs and cycle graphs of odd length, which require Δ + 1
>   colors.